# Facebook like button not work ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

```
 FBSDKLikeControl * likeButton = [[FBSDKLikeControl alloc] init];
likeButton.objectID = @"https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers";//self.shareDic[@"shareLink"];
likeButton.likeControlStyle = FBSDKLikeControlStyleBoxCount;
// Change the style to box count
likeButton.likeControlHorizontalAlignment = FBSDKLikeControlHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
[likeButton isTouchInside];
[shareBackView addSubview:likeButton];
[likeButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.left.equalTo(shareBackView).offset(10);
            make.centerY.equalTo(shareBackView.mas_centerY);

        }];
```

Four months ago it work, but now it not work just a blank page.

[image]

Comment: i am also getting blank fb page when tapping on 'fb like' button.

Comment: i have the same action when tab the button